# how to use the twitter bootstrap framework in a zend framework 1 application?

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap

is it possible to use twitter bootstap on a zend framework ( zf1 ) application and how ?
Alternatively , is there a similar easy and powerful front-end framework i could use ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See below URL i think it is help full to you

**An easy way to display forms with Zend Framework + Bootstrap**

This is designed as an easy drop-in replacement for the normal Zend Forms to work together with Twitter Bootstrap

https://github.com/komola/Bootstrap-Zend-Framework

**Zend Framework & Twitter Bootstrap**

http://blog.herczeg.be/zend-framework-twitter-bootstrap-navigation/

**Twitter Bootstrap’s Zend_Form decorators**

http://engineering.emagister.com/2012/07/08/twitter-bootstraps-zend_form-decorators/

Comment: Hmm, second is a dead link... Anything new on that?