# How to integrate Twitter Bootstrap template with Zend Framework

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2

I've just started using Twitter Bootstrap, and would like to integrate some of these HMTL/CSS templates with an existing Zend Framework that has been developed.  Basically a way to redesign the site that is built on Zend.

Has anyone tried this or know of an approach that might be helpful? I couldn't find other conversations on this. Thanks!!

Comment: found your solution to use bootstrap and zend here. hope it helps.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898817/how-to-use-the-twitter-bootstrap-framework-in-a-zend-framework-1-application][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898817/how-to-use-the-twitter-bootstrap-framework-in-a-zend-framework-1-application

Comment: for the most part it should be updating views and layouts with relevant code and style.